# Setup HomeNetworking

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

If I have 2 computers with wireless adapters (1 has 802.11g, 1 has 802.11b) and I have a wireless router 802.11g. Can I setup a home network (i.e. have 2 computers talk to each other)? Do I need to have internet access from an ISP (e.g. comcast) in order to achieve that?

Comment: of course you don't need internet access. just like with wired you don't need internet access

Comment: Thank you. A related question. But what if I do have internet access, the download rate is 6Mb/s, upload rate is 6M/s. And my computer and my TV has 802.11g and 802.11b wireless adapter respectively. What is the downdspeed from my computer to my TV? 6Mb/s or what 802.11b capable of (which is 11Mb/s)? Thank you.

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors, but from your computer to your TV has nothing to do with your internet line speed whether it exists or not. The problem with wireless is that speeds can fluctuate wildly depending on a lot of things, even those so simple as turning on a microwave in the dwelling. The one thing you can be sure of is that the speed between two points is always limited by the slowest portion of the journey, which in this case would likely be the TV, though not necessarily if the computer happens to be four rooms away from the router and the TV is right next to it.

Comment: @user28287  Your TV has a wireless adaptor, I haven't heard of that. I suppose it'd be the same speed issue if other elements of your network were 802.11b , the question of, would your whole network slow to 802.11b. I'm not sure. Maybe your router would -have to- and only be able to transmit 802.11b. As soon as such a device connects. I don't know but I think that's the issue.. What if a device is 802.11b how will it affect things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need internet access.

Just set up the router (defaults should be fine, but make sure you enable encryption and set a password on the router settings), then configure each PC to receive an IP address via DHCP (this should also be default). After that, the computers should be reachable from each other (of course, further setup may be required, but without knowing your OS or software configuration, it would be impossible to elaborate further).